# Using XCTest files in multiple projects

Tags: swift, xcode8, xctest

The app I work on takes too long for comfort to compile and to run tests on, so I started creating "feature development projects", which are small projects where I do most of the development (while already under version control for the main project) until I integrate the feature into the project by dragging the new classes and tests into the main xcode project. An issue I have run into is making the main target visible to test files in a universal manner. Lets say we have a project named `MyMainProject` and a feature project named `FeatureProject`. For testing in `FeatureProject` I would have to import everything from the main target (of that project) by doing:

```
@testable import FeatureProject
```

That of course won't compile once I integrate the new tests into `MyMainProject`, which would expect the following (to import the main target of the latter project):

```
@testable import MyMainProject
```

My first instinct was to play with the preprocessor to solve the issue, but maybe there is a more elegant way to solve this?

Additional Infromation:

I have `Allow testing Host Application APIs` checked in `General->Testing`

---

Comment: If you want to import everything from the main project into the feature project anyway, how will this speed up compile times?

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing out some unclear wording. Will revise. In the `FeatureProject` I want the main target of `FeatureProject` to be imported. When the test file is run as part of the test suite in `MyMainProject`, I want its main target imported.